# Ionic v1 use webpack instead of gulp

Tags: ionic-framework, webpack, gulp

I have 2 questions:

1. Can I use webpack instead of gulp while running "ionic serve"
2. Can I use webpack instead of gulp while running "ionic build android" ?

Currently the configurations are under:
ionic.project file with the properties: "gulpStartupTasks" and "watchPatterns"

Answer (score 0):

like a ionic team member said on [the ionic forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/can-webpack-dev-server-replace-ionic-serve-cmd/56622): "it would require changing how the core of the CLI works".

So it's not recommended.

But what you can do is build your app with a dedicated npm webpack script, then run "ionic serve" to test your app in development mode.

About the android build, you can run it with the **--no-build** option, to skip the core gulp build tasks :

`ionic cordova run android --no-build`

I made a boilerplate available on github, if you wanna [give a try](https://github.com/rgfactory/ionic-v1-webpack-boilerplate).